# Change the form of equation of surface

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We consider the surface $S$ of the space $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is defined by the equation $2(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz)+3\sqrt{2}(x-z)=1$.

I want to find (using symmetric matrices) an appropriate orthonormal system of coordinates $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ for which the above equation has the form $ax_1^2+by_1^2+cz_1^2=d$, for some $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

The eqquation of the surface $S$ can be written in the form $$\vec{x}^T\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}\vec{x}+\begin{pmatrix}3\sqrt{2} & 0 & -3\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}\vec{x}=1$$ Since that matrix is symmetric it is diagonalizable with orthonormal basis.

Then we have to write the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ is the form $PDP^{-1}$, or not?

What do we do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your equation is defined by a polinomial
\begin{equation*}
P(\vec{x} ) =\vec{x}^T A \vec{x}+v^T\vec{x}+\alpha
\end{equation*}
with 
\begin{equation*}
A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}, \quad v^T=\begin{pmatrix}3\sqrt{2} & 0 & -3\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}\quad \text{and} \quad \alpha=-1.
\end{equation*}

Now you translate the polynomial with a vector $\vec{c} $
\begin{equation*}
P(\vec{x}+\vec{c} ) =(\vec{x}+\vec{c} ) ^T A (\vec{x}+\vec{c}) +v^T(\vec{x}+\vec{c} ) +\alpha
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
P(\vec{x}+\vec{c} ) =\vec{x}^T A \vec{x}+ 2\vec{c}^T A \vec{x}+\vec{c}^T A \vec{c}+v^T \vec{x}+v^T \vec{c}  +\alpha
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
P(\vec{x}+\vec{c} ) =\vec{x}^T A \vec{x}+\underline{ 2\vec{c}^T A \vec{x}+v^T \vec{x}} +\vec{c}^T A \vec{c}+v^T \vec{c}  +\alpha
\end{equation*}

And you want the underlined part to be zero. This gives you a new equation and solving it would give you the vector $\vec{c} $.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to eliminate the linear terms of the equation using a special translation. After that, in order to eliminate the mixed terms, you have to diagonalize the matrix you wrote above. Then you'll have the diagonal matrix and your equation.

Comment: Ah ok!  But how can we find the translation that we need to eliminate the linear terms?

Comment: @MaryStar Substitute $x\to x'-a$ &c into the equation. The condition that the linear terms vanish will give you a system of linear equations in the three displacements.